# Axon for choreography, DisallowReplay or Subscribing?

Tags: axon

I've wrote some choreography-based inter-service communication using Axon Framework.

https://github.com/jinyoung/lab-shop-eventsourcing4

Event Storming Model is here: https://dev.msaez.io/#/storming/129002f0e576ba8633b5b7f4520abbe1

The order service publishes "OrderPlacedEvent" and the delivery service takes the event with EventHandler:

#OrderAggregate.java in order service:

```
@Aggregate
@Data
@ToString
public class OrderAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private Long id;
    private String productId;
    private Integer qty;
    private String customerId;
    private java.math.BigDecimal amount;
    private String status;
    private String address;

    public OrderAggregate(){}

    @CommandHandler
    public OrderAggregate(OrderCommand command){

        OrderPlacedEvent event = new OrderPlacedEvent();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(command, event);     
        apply(event);

    }
..
```

#PolicyHandler.java in delivery service:

```
@Service
@ProcessingGroup("delivery")
public class PolicyHandler{

    @Autowired
    CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @EventHandler  
    @DisallowReplay
    @AllowReplay(false)
    public void wheneverOrderPlaced_AddToDeliveryList(OrderPlacedEvent orderPlaced, ReplayStatus status){
        System.out.println(orderPlaced.toString());  // called again when it restarted

        AddToDeliveryListCommand command = new AddToDeliveryListCommand();
        command.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());
        command.setOrderId(orderPlaced.getId());
        commandGateway.send(command);
    }
    
}
```

The problem is when the delivery service is restarted, all the EventHandler is called again with the 'OrderPlacedEvent'. That occurs undesired problem - reproducing the delivery start command again.

So, I tried to use @DisallowReplay option - that doesn't work. still receives the all the events.
And So I tried to set the configuration

```
axon:
  axonserver:
    servers: localhost
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      delivery:
        mode: subscribing
      #  source: eventbus
```

In this case, the EventHandler never get called. Is it right that the event is firstly stored in Event Store and after it is sent to Event Bus? So I tried to set the 'source' value to eventBus, there was some Bean error from Spring Boot again.

What I want is that the subscribing service receives the event only once even if the service is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you miss is a persisted token store. The progress the event processor made is now not stored, so when starting up again it starts from the beginning again.

If this is just for local development you could set the processor to start at the [tail](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/4.6/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#custom-tracking-token-position) instead, to solve the problem. For production you would want to use a relational database (using JPA or JDBC) to store the tokens, or MongoDB (using the [Axon mongo extension](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-mongo)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After configuring database connection for the app and some JPA settings, the default TokenProvider is provided and works well now. I didn't require any annotation or setting like 'subscribing', Axon framework did all the things automatically. Thank you.